# I am trying to change a variable through reference. However the variable changes only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pass-by-reference

```
//This variable I am trying to change
int levelCount = 0;

 IEnumerator LoadScene(float waitTime){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    LevelCount(ref levelCount); //through this method I am trying to increase the variable levelCount by one
}

//This function should achieve it but it doesn’t work
public void LevelCount(ref int thislevelCount){
    thislevelCount ++;
}
```

I am trying to change the variable levelCount through the method LevelCount(ref int lvlCount).

Comment: Try to replace 'thislevelCount ++;' by 'thislevelCount += 1';

Comment: @Elec1 that's exactly the same thing https://dotnetfiddle.net/G3lHYU

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to address the variable as a reference. Simply leave it as public void LevelCount(int thislevelCount).

Or rather you could simplify your code if you do not intend to expand upon the LevelCount method.

```
 IEnumerator LoadScene(float waitTime){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(levels[levelCount]);
    levelCount+=1;
}
```

Comment: I did try to put levelCount ++; in the LoadScene method but it was increasing by one only when the method was called and then it returned to 0. I'll try however the LevelCount(int thislevelCount);

Comment: So it somehow doesn't work for me. including it in the IEnumerator method

Comment: I think I know your issue, knowing that it sets back to 0 upon use. Whenever you load a new scene, variables will be reset across your objects. So levelCount goes back to 0. Try making it a static variable (public static int levelCount;).

Alternatively, use a singleton https://videlais.com/2021/02/20/singleton-global-instance-pattern-in-unity/

Comment: Yes thank you public static int solved it! The variable was resetting with every scene load. Let me check how to mark your comment as "solved" answer..